# Is it possible to add the Rhythmbox volume controls in the Sound Menu?

Tags: rhythmbox, indicator-sound

I can see Rhythmbox pause/play controls in Sound Menu. But I also want the Rhythmbox volume slider controls (as opposed to master volume controls). Is it possible to add them under sound menu or are there any alternatives? (I'm on Ubuntu 12.04). I saw some articles about "Panflute" but it seems to have been abandoned.

Comment: What for do you need Rhythmbox volume controls in the Sound Menu when you already have volume controls in the Sound Menu? I don't think it will look nice.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu I keep radio running on Rhythmbox. Sometimes I want to analyze some files on Audacity, at that time temporarily I want to mute/reduce volume of Rhythmbox alone.

Comment: Well, for mute you have the "Pause" button.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu yes, but it breaks down the connection with radio channel and there is a time lag to start it again. Actually, that's what I'll resort to if there is no other way..

Comment: This doesn't happen when you have a good internet connection.

Comment: @Mitch No my question is different. I ALREADY have play/pause controls. I want volume slider control in addition.